# Can I use flavored beers in beer bread?

Tags: bread, beer

I'm making beer bread and only have blue moon or leineys lemon shandy. Would these work without a fruity flavor overpowering the bread?

Answer (score 4):

I've made rather good bread with Hoegaarden, so I assume any witbier like Blue Moon would be fine. There is a noticeable flavor contribution, but it isn't overpowering or unpleasant (unless you don't like witbier, I guess). I don't think I'd use the shandy, but it wouldn't necessarily be overpowering - the bread would probably just taste somewhat lemony.

Answer (score 3):

I've made beer bread with Dreamweaver Wheat (gave it a sweet banana-like flavor), Sunshine Pils (a nice savory hoppy flavor), and Guinness (a darker bread with those dark bread flavors). All of them worked out well on their own.

I wouldn't recommend Summer Shandy because it's sort of an "adulterated" beer (part beer, part spiked lemonade) and it would probably be too sweet, but Blue Moon is likely fine.

Comment: Acid from the lemon in the Shandy might also slightly throw off the pH balance of the recipe.  Stick with Blue Moon.

Answer (score 1):

I made apple beer bread with the apple flavored cider type beer. I put a chopped up apple in it and a cinnamon crumb topping. It is wonderful.